# New Category - custom taxonomy

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy

When you click on Posts > Category and Add a new Category - is this new Category an example of a custom taxonomy?

I had a read of https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies but still didn't make much sense by the end.

Comment: This is in general speaking terms a category, which is in technical terms a term of the build in taxonomy `category`

Comment: I didn't understand anything after 'technical terms a'.

Comment: Maybe some articles which Justin Tadlock wrote, may help you understanding the 'logic under the hood' of WP. Take a look here for [Custom taxonomies](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/05/06/custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress-28) or here for [Post types and taxonomies](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/08/20/linking-terms-to-a-specific-post) or his total [archive](http://justintadlock.com/archives). He is one of many ppl who explain it often better than the WP codex does.

Answer (score 0):

No Category is an taxonomy but not an custom taxonomy. Custom taxonomies need to be created via code, and you will have an different type of **categories.**